# Bias of the Kerneldistribution (KDE) little o-Notation

Tags: limits, analysis

I am currently studying nonparametric estimation thus I am working with the Kernel density distribution. I am trying to understand the proof of the bias of the KDE.
When working out the bias of the KDE you use the Taylor expansion, so far so good. But I do not understand the o(h^2) term, why are we using it and why are we not putting in the "true" term such as:

$$\frac{1}{3}h^3y^3p^´´´(x_0)$$

Or what does o(h^2) mean?
I am not a mathematician, so I would be very happy if anyone could explain it to me.

Thank you a lot

Best regards
Alexandra

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TyPT.png)

Comment: Hi! So, as this is your first question here, some heads ups: do not use links to images for your questions, write your question with MathJax. It also isn't clear why you need help with this on this site. How did googling for "little o Notation" not help? Why doesn't the explanation at the bottom of your image help you? On this site, people expect you to put in at least a minimum amount of effort to answer the question yourself, most importantly since that way it is much clearer what the poster wants and how to help.

Comment: First of all, thank your for your advices. I don't understand the little o Notation, of course I googled it but I don't understand it in this situation, in "simple english" what means o(h^2) is a smaller order term compared to h? when h › 0.